# Debian 10 + KDE Plasma Reboot/Log Out/Lock Screen not working

Tags: debian, kde, multi-monitor, plasma

I am using Debian 10 with KDE Plasma (installed KDE via Debian installer directly). My problem is that, for example, if my screen locks or I logout or try to restart the PC, my screen gets blurred and the login screen is not shown. After that happens, I need to reboot via the physical power button.
Another similar problem is that if the PC locks itself due to inactivity, the same thing happens and I can't login nor see a login screen. A fresh install didn't help.

I have a dual screen setup and I am using SDDM.